# Trying to exclude certain wpf windows when getting a collection of windows in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I wrote some code to get a `WindowCollection` using `WindowCollection handles = Application.Current.Windows;`

It works fine, however I get the WindowCollection by pushing a button in a window called SelectScreenShots which opens from a window called AskAQuestionDialog. In the end the windows are rendered as bitmaps and displayed in SelectScreenShots. I think you can guess what the user does after they are displayed in this last window.

I want to exclude AskAQuestionDialog and WindowCollection though from `handles`, preferably before I render and display them. Someone mentioned using `Object.ReferenceEquals` to get them and remove them, but i am not sure exactly how to implement this. Here is how they are gathered and rendered.

```
public static List<BitmapSource> RenderWindows()
{
    WindowCollection handles = Application.Current.Windows;
    List<BitmapSource> renderWindows = new List<BitmapSource>();
    foreach (Window window in handles)
    {
        double width = window.Width;
        double height = window.Height;
        RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = (new RenderTargetBitmap((int)width, (int)height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default));
        bitmap.Render(window);
        renderWindows.Add(bitmap);
    }

    return renderWindows;
}
```

How can I remove these two windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some LINQ will surely look better:

```
public static List<BitmapSource> RenderWindows()
{
    var windows = Application.Current.Windows
                                     .OfType<Window>()
                                     .Where(x => x.GetType() != typeof(AskAQuestionDialog));

    var bitmaps = new List<BitmapSource>();

    foreach (var window in windows)
    {
        var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)window.width, (int)window.height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default));
        bitmap.Render(window);

        bitmaps.Add(bitmap);
    }

    return bitmaps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say to just check their type, if you know that a certain type you'll never want to include:

```
public static List<BitmapSource> RenderWindows()
{
    WindowCollection handles = Application.Current.Windows;
    List<BitmapSource> renderWindows = new List<BitmapSource>();
    foreach (Window window in handles)
    {
        if (window.GetType() == typeof(AskAQuestionDialog))
            continue;

        double width = window.Width;
        double height = window.Height;
        RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = (new RenderTargetBitmap((int)width, (int)height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default));
        bitmap.Render(window);
        renderWindows.Add(bitmap);
    }

    return renderWindows;
}
```